# Android Database Sqlite Retrieving data with multiple where's

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to make my database readable having in consideration that only the "categoria" that where selected are retrieved, so I developed this code:

```
plus = praia+ cafe+serv+rest+hot+muse+mon+escolas;
String dados[] = new String[plus];

//categoria is the name of the colum
String query = "categoria = ?";

for (i = 1; i < plus; i++) {
    query = query+ " OR categoria = ?";
}

//if == 1 its active if == 0 its unactive;
if (praia == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Praias";
}

if (serv == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Servicos";
}

if (cafe == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Cafes";
}

if (rest == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Restaurantes";
}

if (hot == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Hoteis";
}

if (muse == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Museus";
}

if (mon == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Monumentos";
}

if (escolas == 1) {
   dados[cont]= "Escolas";
}

String[] projections ={VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Nome, VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Categoria, VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Latitude, VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Longitude};

//error here
cursor = db.query(VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Table_name, projections, query, dados, null, null, null);
```

And this is the logcat:

```
05-01 07:58:13.131    1435-1435/prosis.guiatour D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-01 07:58:13.131    1435-1435/prosis.guiatour W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ac7ba8)
 05-01 07:58:13.171    1435-1435/prosis.guiatour E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: prosis.guiatour, PID: 1435
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{prosis.guiatour/prosis.guiatour.Lista}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 3 is null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 3 is null
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
        at prosis.guiatour.VianaDbHelper.getInfor(VianaDbHelper.java:123)
        at prosis.guiatour.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What do you think is causing the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving the SQL database an array to use as criteria with null bindings. That means that your array `dados` has null values and the database sees that and is throwing an exception. This is because of the way that you are initializing the `dados` array.

Looking at your code, I don't see where `cont` is initialized, but I will assume that you set it to zero. Now the problem I see is that you never increment `cont`, yet you use it as the index for every single assignment to a location in the `dados` array. As you see, that just means you're overwriting the same location every time, so assuming all of those values are 1, you would have an array of size 8, but only the location of `cont` would have any data in it and your array would look like

```
{ Escolas, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }
```

to the database, and it would have to throw an exception.

In order to fix this problem, simply increment `cont` as follows:

```
plus = praia + cafe + serv + rest + hot + muse + mon + escolas;
String dados[] = new String[plus];

// categoria is the name of the column
String query = "categoria = ?";

for(i = 1; i < plus; i++){
    query = query + " OR categoria = ?";
}

//if == 1 its active if == 0 its unactive;
cont = 0;

if(praia == 1){
    dados[cont] = "Praias";
    cont++;
}

if(serv == 1){
    dados[cont] = "Servicos";
    cont++;
}

if(cafe == 1){
   dados[cont] = "Cafes";
   cont++;
}

if(rest == 1){
   dados[cont] = "Restaurantes";
   cont++;
}

if(hot == 1){
   dados[cont] = "Hoteis";
   cont++;
}

if(muse == 1){
   dados[cont] = "Museus";
   cont++;
}

if(mon == 1){
   dados[cont] = "Monumentos";
   cont++;
}

if(escolas == 1){
   dados[cont] = "Escolas";
   cont++;
}

String[] projections ={VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Nome, VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Categoria, VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Latitude, VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Longitude};
cursor = db.query(VianaContract.NewLocalInfo.Table_name, projections, query, dados, null, null, null);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Funny thing i had that part where in each one the cont would increment, but i erased it cus i though was part of the code that i didnt need anymore :P

Comment: Great to hear! It's funny how often bugs get created when you forget why a piece of code is present and you delete it.